# Change color of anchor text when mouse is placed over the containing div element

Tags: css

The text color is changing when I move the mouse over the `<a>` link but not changing when I place it over the `<div>` that contains it.

I want to change the color of the anchor text when mouse is placed over the containing div too.

```css
.more_games{
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
 }
.more_games h4{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  color: red;
}
.more_games:hover{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.more_games h4 a:hover{
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_games">
  <h4><a href="#">More Games</a></h4>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the colour on the hover of the div itself, i.e. instead of

```
.more_games h4 a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
```

...which will only change the colour of the`<a>` element when it itself is hovered, use:

```
.more_games:hover h4 a{
    color: #fff;
}
```

... which will change the colour of `<a>` when the *div* is hovered.

You can see it working here:

```css
.more_games{
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
 }
.more_games h4{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  color: red;
}
.more_games:hover{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.more_games:hover h4 a{
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_games">
  <h4><a href="#">More Games</a></h4>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
.more_games:hover h4 a { color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace following code

```
.more_games h4 a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
```

with

```
.more_games:hover h4 a{
    color: #fff;
}
```