# Change color of anchor text when mouse is placed over the div

Tags: html, css

I am working on my college project and I was facing a problem with my CSS so I googled my problem and got an [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409744). This code solved my problem. My question though, is there any other way to get the same output? I mean there are lot of ways to use CSS to get the same result. I don't want to use jQuery/JavaScript. If so then please let me know.

```css
.more_games{
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
 }
.more_games h4{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
  color: red;
}
.more_games:hover{
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.more_games:hover h4 a{
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_games">
  <h4><a href="#">More Games</a></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems like the only way to do so using pure css

Comment: Your code is fine. Is there a reason you want another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the anchor and heading inherit the color by its parent.

```css
.more_games a {
  color: inherit;
}
.more_games{
  color: red;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
 }
.more_games h4{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
.more_games:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#74ABDD, #74ABDD 49.9%, #498DCB 50.1%, #498DCB 100%); 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_games">
  <h4><a href="#">More Games</a></h4>
</div>
```